# Matlab: creating listener on tcpip object

Tags: matlab, listener, tcp

I am trying to implement a "multithreaded" program in Matlab. It is not *actually* multithreaded, but it consists on a main script (A) interacting with other scripts (B,C...) in other Matlab instances via TCP/IP.

The way I tried to do this is to create a listener on the tcpip object (srv) :

```
func = @(src, evnt) disp('booh');
l = listener(srv, 'BytesAvailable', 'PostSet', func );
```

which returns me

```
Undefined function 'listener' for input arguments of type 'tcpip'.
```

I'm new to listeners in Matlab, so I might be missing something here. In case not, is there a clean way to know when data has been received ? (I prefer not having to do an infinite loop checking the value of `srv.BytesAvailable`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to achieve this is to set the `srv.BytesAvailableFcn` property to a function callback.